# How to point a Dokku app at the root domain of the dokku server

Tags: nginx, dns, docker, dokku

How do I point a dokku app that will set up in the dokku server, to point at the root domain of the server itself. Suppose my domain is `apps.com` and the app to be implemented is called `botapp`. If I use virtualhost naming, and do `git remote add dokku dokku@apps.com:botapp` it will get pointed at `botapp.apps.com`. What do I do to get the `botapp` pointed at `apps.com` itself (the root domain).

Also, how do I know what port a dokku app is rooting, inspite of using subdomains (virtualhost naming)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of v0.3.10, Dokku ships with a domains plugin. This lets you easily add domains to your app. By default your app is located at `myapp.mydomain.com`. If you want your app to be accessible via the root domain, then just add the root domain as one of your app's domains. `dokku domains:add myapp mydomain.com`.

That was really straightforward, the docs need to be updated to reflect this, really.

For your second question, your app is not visible to the outside world. Your app is running inside its own docker container, with its own local IP address. If you still want to find out what port your app has exposed, you can run `docker ps` on your server.

Comment: I thought I had to remove the global domain for a second, but it ended up being that I needed to set up letsencrypt plugin again since Chrome defaultly requests a secure site. I also found out that having domains that I haven't yet been pointed to your server will inhibit the letsencrypt process.